# Vanilla JS, can't replace backslash in a string fetched from the DOM

Tags: javascript, string, dom, replace

I try to replace all occurences of `\` in a string, but I can't find the way, even after searching on the web and here.

This is what I tried :

```
$ node
> var x = 'foo\bar\base'
> x.replace(/\\/g, '/');
'foo\bar\base'
```

I expect `foo/bar/base` but the string is unchanged.

Same thing with `split()` :

```
> x.split('\\')
[ 'foo\bar\base' ]
```

**Context**: this is from the DOM, I get this string with

```
var node = document.querySelector(sel);
node.innerText.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

**Edit** there's a confusion between my try in [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and what I can have in real browser, check @Jeffrey Westerkamp comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686637/1399816)

Comment: Replace returns a new string

Comment: Technically speaking, there are no backslahes in your string.  When you input a backslash character in a string literal, it's actually an escape character for what comes next.  So, `\b` is the character.  (I don't know off the top of my head *what* character, but it's something.)  If you want backslashes in your string literal, use `\\`.  That effectively cancels the escape and becomes a single backslash in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

escape the backslashes in your original string:

```
var x = 'foo\\bar\\base'
```

explanation: the `\` is the default escape character - in your original string, each `\b` pair is a backspace - to include a backslash in a string literal, you need to escape it, i.e. `\\`

Comment: Added some **context** from my post. I get the string from the DOM

Comment: try `node.innerText = node.innerText.replace(/\\/g, '/');`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution :

```
node.innerText.split('\\').join("/")
```

Comment: Still, this is weird. writing `var x = "foo\bar\baz"` in node `v6.11` results in `"foo\bar\baz"`, but doing the same thing in the chrome console results in `"fooaraz"`. (?)

Comment: Update: I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43610251/6361314) that explains the concept that's likely to be at work here.